# Database Management

Tags: database-normalization

what is the advantages of Normalizing. And why we do that. can anybody explain me about that???????

Comment: You could probably get some hints from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Following are advantages of Normalization

1) Avoids data modification (INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE) anomalies as each data item lives in One place, avoid data redundancy

2) Greater flexibility in getting the expected data in atomic granular

3) Normalization is conceptually cleaner and easier to maintain and change as your needs change

4) Fewer null values and less opportunity for inconsistency

5) A better handle on database security

6) Increased storage efficiency

7) The normalization process helps maximize the use of clustered indexes, which is the most powerful and useful type of index available. As more data is separated into multiple
tables because of normalization, the more clustered indexes become available to help
speed up data access.

Comment: plagiarized answers should probably be attributed: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050826.asp